# .save() is not a Function in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've got "user.save is not a function" error when I try to run these code. I don't know why. I'll happy if you figure out that.

```
let updateUserInfo = (data) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const user = await db.User.findOne({
                where: { id: data.id }
            })

            if (user) {
                user.first_name = data.first_name;
                user.last_name = data.last_name;
                user.email = data.email;

                await user.save();
                resolve();
            }
            else {
                resolve();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error shows your code have mistake.
that is if you wants to pass findAll method with async and await use it instead of your code:

```
var [err, user] = await to(
  db.User.findOne({
    where: { id: data.id },
  })
);
```

then use user.save()
i hope it helpful.

Comment: I don't think my code wrong because I've run that code successfully before but when I change database from mysql to progres it's wrong, so do you know why

Comment: @Zombani i'm not familiar with postgresql but this error is not database error.

Answer (score 0):

You miss raw = false, most likely in db you have set raw = true, now you want to update you need to switch to raw = false

- code :
  `const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { id: data.id }, raw: false})`